# Android Volley POST JsonObject and get JsonArray or JsonObject or Other response

Tags: android, android-volley

in volley we have some ability to retrieve data from server such as jsonObject,jsonArray and String. in this below sample we can get simply jsonObject or jsonArray response from server,

```
public static void POST(HashMap<String, String> params, final Listeners.ServerResponseListener listener) {
    JsonObjectRequest req1 = new JsonObjectRequest(ApplicationController.URL, new JSONObject(params),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.e("Response:", response.toString());
                    if (listener != null)
                        listener.onResultJsonObject(response);
                    else
                        Log.e(TAG,"Error: SetServerResponse interface not set");
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
        }
    });
    ApplicationController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req1);
}
```

my problem is i want to send jsonObject from this method and get jsonArray or jsonObject from server, and i can not get simply array from server with this method. for example i must be filter server response with this jsonObject:

```
HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("token", "AbCdEfGh123456");
params.put("search_count", "10");
params.put("order_by", "id");
```

server return jsonArray and i can not get that with Volley response

Comment: Volley also supports `JsonArrayRequest`..

Comment: @akash93 yes thats right, how to post OBJECT? i dont have any json array such as parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class RetreiveData {

    public static final String TAG = RetreiveData.class.getSimpleName();

    public static void POST(String localhost, final HashMap<String, String> params, final Listeners.ServerResponseListener listener) {
        StringRequest post = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, localhost, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    if (listener != null)
                        listener.onResponse(response.toString());
                    else
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error: SetServerResponse interface not set");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("Error: ", error.toString());
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> map = params;
                return map;
            }

            @Override
            public RetryPolicy getRetryPolicy() {
                setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                        5000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
                return super.getRetryPolicy();
            }
        };
        ApplicationController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(post);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the source code of [JsonArrayRequest](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley/blob/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/JsonArrayRequest.java#L96). There is a constructor which takes in a `JSONObject`. You should check it out

Comment: this is not my answer sir. my problem is send json object such as simple request from server with Volley POST method and get JsonArray response.

Comment: that is exactly what this does... You can use it  to send a JSONObject  as POST params whilst expecting a JSONArray as response.

Comment: I tried your method and first it gave me an error for not recognizing the constructor. Apparently volley version 1.0.0 does not have it. I had to switch in gradle to `compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'` in order to have it. Thanks for the info.